# How to get current restrictions from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restrictions

In iOS, I can set Restrictions on the device to block specific apps or actions (also known as Parental Control).

Is that a way to access the current permissions set in the device within my app? Like an API or something?

Particularly, I'm interested to see wether Safari is allowed or not.

Comment: I spent some time looking yesterday, couldn't find an API and found a lot of people saying there wasn't an API. I hope you find one, I'll use it!